# Sort 2d Array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2d array with 2 columns and 10000rows.
I want to sort it based on the second column values and also want the corresponding first column values to be sorted.
example.
Array - 
(13,10)
(24, 15)
(2, 12)
(56, 7)

sorted output required - 
(56, 7)
(13,10)
(2, 12)
(24, 15)

I want to do it in PHP. So is there some inbuilt function which i can use to sort these way ?

Comment: Are the first column values or second column values each unique values?

Comment: usort() -  but why does 12 come before 10? Your sort rule isn't particularly obvious

Comment: I personally can't visualise what you're working with, could you post the output of doing: echo '<pre>'.print_r($thearray,true).'</pre>';

Answer (score 0):

What about usort? Look there: [PHP.net-usort](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)